# Apple pay not completed using Authorize.net CIM - Stuck on [Apple Pay] Validating merchant

Tags: woocommerce, authorize.net, applepay, authorize.net-cim

I have implemented apple pay on my site using Authorize.net CIM extension and add all the details of sandbox account of Authorize.net. I can see the Apple pay button on my web, but when I try to make a payment it shows me an error

> **Apple pay not completed**
>   This website was not able to complete the payment. Please try again.

I tried to see logs and every time I try to make a payment the, last line of log is

```
`[Apple Pay] Validating merchant`
```

I have verified my domain but my site is in a sub-directory.

I have tried enabling/disabling all the options including test mode and capturing payment/authorization from the plugin settings.

I expect apple pay button to process my payments successfully

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible causes of that error but here are two good places to look first:

1. Your back end must make a session token request to Apple Pay and return a session token to the front end.
2. Your back end must eventually request your payment processor to process the transaction.

If either of those two requests are failing, it's likely that you would get that error message in the front end.

Take a look at the Safari Network tab to find out what your front end is sending to the server, and what it's receiving from the server.

And look at what the server's logs are showing.